# How to print PDF in VB.net or C#

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0

Could anyone tell me how to print PDF Document in VB.net or C#
I made a quick search about this subject but I didn't find anything appropriate to me

Comment: What have you tried? (You are expected to have at least tried to find a solution – eg. google for other's solutions – before asking here; please show your work so far.)

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to print to a PDF as well.  Is it a PrintDocument, Crystal Report, Excel, Word, etc.  More info (and a serious attempt at the code first) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print pdf file directly without PDF reader or PDF printer driver or application. You need a at least PDF Reader installed in your pc to print pdf file. or you can use any third party tool to print any pdf file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", "/P " + "D:\\YourDoc.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00c2c76c-9e09-47d0-b34d-52c1a956f15f/how-to-print-pdf-file-programatically-using-c-code)

First download the `itextpdf` library which is open source library from the [following link/iTextSharp](http://www.itextpdf.com/)

Now follow the following steps to get started :

Step 1: First create an instance of document object

```
Document myDocument= new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Step 2: Now create a writer that listens to this doucment and writes the document to desired Stream.

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream("Salman.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Step 3: Open the document now using

```
myDocument.Open();
```

Step 4: Now add some contents to the document

```
myDocument.add( new Paragraph ( "First Pdf File made by Salman using iText"));
```

Step 5: Remember to close the documnet

```
myDocument.close();
```

The full code to get started is given below :

// Code

```
    using System;

    using System.IO;

    using System.Diagnostics;



    using iTextSharp.text;

    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;



    public class iTextDemo 

    {

      public static void Main() 

     {

      Console.WriteLine("iText Demo");



  // step 1: creation of a document-object

       Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());



      try 

      {



   // step 2:

   // Now create a writer that listens to this doucment and writes the document to desired Stream.



       PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream("Salman.pdf", FileMode.Create));



   // step 3:  Open the document now using

        myDocument.Open();



   // step 4: Now add some contents to the document

       myDocument.Add(new Paragraph("First Pdf File made by Salman using iText"));



       }

      catch(DocumentException de) 

      {

       Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);

      }

       catch(IOException ioe) 

       {

        Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);

       }



  // step 5: Remember to close the documnet

      myDocument.Close();

     }

    }
```

Also refer to the following link : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/generatepdf.aspx